# When back, if I say "Out of office until Thursday"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, ambiguity, dates

I am always confused when I get an email stating "out of office until Thursday". Is the sender back on Thursday or still out of office (o.o.o.) on Thursday and only back on Friday? Is there a good reference that defines the meaning? Please do not tell me that it would be better to state "back on Thursday", since this does not answer the question.

Comment: To me, 'until Thursday' means they'll be back in on Thursday.

Comment: This question is worded much better than the duplicate

Comment: @guanome I agree, that was second hit in Google search for "what it mean away until", also there is one more "duplicate" I found on SE [Is “until” inclusive or exclusive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33340/is-until-inclusive-or-exclusive)?

Answer (score 7):

Until ***x*** means that the change occurs on/at ***x***:

> I am here until Friday. | From Friday I will not be here.

or

> I am playing football until 7pm. | At 7pm I finish playing football.

or

> The store is closed until March.  | In March the store opens.

In your example:

> I am out of the office until Thursday.  |  From Thursday I am back in the office.