# "until" as used in this sentence

Tags: endings

A friend of mine received a letter stating the following: "The committee has issued orders to suspend John Doe for 30 days from the 20th of April 2018 until the 19th of May 2018." So, does the suspension end on the day of the 19th of May, or the 20th of May?
Thanks.

Comment: Counting 20 April as the first day of suspension, a 30-day period lasts until 19 May with 20 May being the first day without suspension. It may be irrelevant, since 19–20 May is a weekend.

Comment: The ambiguity of statements like 'The committee has issued orders to suspend John Doe until the 19th of May 2018' has been discussed before. Essentially, to resolve the problem of undetermined inclusiveness, a follow-up statement like 'He will be able to play from the 20th' is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does "until \[date\]" mean "before that date"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38169/does-until-date-mean-before-that-date) Also [When back, if I say “Out of office until Thursday”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196928/when-back-if-i-say-out-of-office-until-thursday) and probably others.

Comment: The ambiguity of ‘end on’ matches that of ‘until’.